# build array to represent company Hierarchy structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Lets say that I have the following definition table structure:

`id(int),related_to(int),description(text`)

and the table contains data similar to:

```
id   related_to     description
1        0          departmen1
2        1          section1
3        2          devision1
4        0          departmen2
5        4          section2
6        4          etc....
```

I need a SQL statement or PHP code to represent each Hierarchy in a seperate array element.

The result must be

```
$data=array(
0=>'department1','section1','devision1'
2=>'departmen2','section2','devision2'
3=> 'departmen1','section3',.......
);
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: A SQL statement can not return hierarchical datatypes, can it?

Comment: Are there any limit of how deep the hierarchy can be?

Comment: No thers is no limitation of the deep of the hierarchy,

Answer (score 3):

The best way to work with tree-like structures in PHP is with objects. A good example can be found [here](http://www.gravitywell.co.uk/blog/post/how-to-create-a-php-tree-object-using-parent-child-notation).

Add a function to the tree object that returns children in your desired array format, and calls the same function on child objects. With one function call on the top-level object you'll receive an array of all children in the format you need. See [Tree Traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) for more information on recursive functions.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, **Nested Sets** solve this issue much better. Using recursive functions at the application level wastes a lot of network time, especially if you have a very large structure. While it might be a bit strange to work with, once you have the functions in place to manipulate nested sets, they becomes easy to use.

See: [Managing Hierarchical Data In MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Nested sets can handle an infinitely deep tree and can return the entire tree with parent-child relationships in a single query. You can also return a "lineage" with a single query without resorting to recursion or application sorting.

Once you get the data back from the single SQL query, you can easily sort it into a generic tree structure in your PHP application for display or further processing.